# Manually instantiate a Controller in MVC 6 alpha4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing some experimentation with MVC 6 alpha 4. Trying to activate a controller manually and returning it instead of HomeController but this doesn't work. Any help please..

So far I have created my own controller factory with this code.

```
 public class MyControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    public object CreateController(ActionContext actionContext)
    {
    var actionDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor as Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor;

    Type controllerType = Type.GetType("Hello.Controllers.MyController");
    var controller = _typeActivator.CreateInstance(_serviceProvider, controllerType);

    actionContext.Controller = controller;
    _controllerActivator.Activate(controller, actionContext);

    return controller;
    }
}
```

I have debugged the code. The constructor of  `MyController` gets called and `MyController` is being returned from the `CreateController` method but I get the error. The debugger never reaches to `IActionResult Index()`.  Here is the error that I get.

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,      Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder,     Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ReflectedActionExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What does "instead of HomeController" mean? Why not just change your routes so that your "HomeController" isn't chosen here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

Firstly, `MyController` needs to inherit from `HomeController`.
Secondly, I need to change the 'controller' value in RouteData before activating the controller.

```
actionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "My";
```