# Manually create controllers in MVC 6 with custom IControllerFactory implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Based on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325854/manually-instantiate-a-controller-in-mvc-6-alpha4) I created custom controller factory for instantiating controllers based on some logic (for making pluggable architecture).

For test purposes everything is kinda hard-coded.

```
var controller = Bootstrapper.GetInstance<Controller>("TestModuleApi");

actionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "TestModuleApi";
actionContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Get";
var returnController = _controllerActivator.Create(actionContext, controller.GetType());

return returnController;
```

`Boostrapper.GetInstance()` gets the controller instance with MEF from the folder with exported controllers.

When I open the default route Home/Index the code goes through here and the `returnController` variable is instance of the desired controller. Even though I get the error saying

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/TestModuleApi/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml.
```

I've also tried really simple approach to make `CreateController` to return whatever I want:

```
actionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "MyApi";
actionContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Get";

return new MyApiController();
```

Here I am overriding every call to `CreateController` to return `MyApiController` instance. In this case `MyApiController` inherits `HomeApiController`. Still when I go to `/api/HomeApi/Get` for example I get the values from the `HomeApiController`, not `MyApiController`.

How is it possible in custom `IControllerFactory` implementation to instantiate whatever controller instance we want?

**UPDATE:** When I am debugging the first code I can see that the constructor of the `TestModuleApiController` is called, but `Get` action is never called.

Comment: On the first issue, from what I can see the issue isn't with the creation of the controller, but that the controller is trying to return a View that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, the `returnController` variable has the instance that I want to have, but the `Get` action is never called.